# Proving $a_{n+1} = \beta a_n + (1-\beta) a_{n-1}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $0<\beta <1$ and $a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb R$.  I want to show that this sequence converges:

$$a_{n+1} = \beta a_n + (1-\beta) a_{n-1}$$

Furthermore, it is given that there you can explicitly formulate the sequence as $$c_1\lambda_1^n+c_2\lambda_2^n$$

I played it through with $a_5$ and if I did not make any mistakes I ended up with $$2\beta^2(a_1-a_0)+2\beta(-a_1+a_0)+a_1$$

I can see that there is a pattern but how do I reexpress it as $c_1\lambda_1^n+c_2\lambda_2^n$? And if I manage to do it, how would I be sure that this works for all $n$  and prove that the $a_n$ converges? Any hints?

Comment: This is a linear recurrence; the standard way of finding a closed form for such a recurrence is by finding the roots of its *characteristic polynomial*; see this link (or search wikipedia): https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Characteristic_polynomial#Linear_recurrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the kind of séquences satisfying:$$(1) \quad u_{n+1}=au_n+bu_{n-1}$$ we solove the algebric equation:$$(E) \quad t^2-at-b=0$$ If $(E)$ has two solutions $q_1$ and $q_2$ the sequences realizing $(1)$ are :$$u_n=\lambda q_1^n+\mu q_2^n$$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two constants.

Using this, you can proof that $a_n=\lambda+\mu(\beta-1)^n$, the $\lambda$ is the limit.

Using: $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\lambda+\mu=a_0 \\ \lambda+\mu(\beta-1)=a_1\end{array}\right.$$  you can easily find the value of $\lambda$.

$$\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star$$
$$\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star$$

An other way to proove convergence is  to put: $$b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$$
Since:

$$a_{n+1}-a_n= (\beta-1)(a_n-a_{n-1})$$ the séquence $(b_n)$ is a geometric sequence with reason $q=\beta-1$ and the first term is $b_1=a_1-a_0$ , then $b_n=b_1.q^{n-1}=b_1.(\beta-1)^{n-1}$

We have $$b_n+b_{n-1} + \cdots + b_1=a_n-a_0=b_1(1+ \cdots + q^{n-1})=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q} (a_1-a_0)$$

Then:  $$ a_n=a_0+\frac{1-q^n}{1-q} (a_1-a_0)$$  and  $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n=a_0+\frac{a_1-a_0}{1-q}=a_0+\frac{a_1-a_0}{2-\beta}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I just do not understand the last two lines where you define $a_0$ and $a_1$. Couldn't I just say that, if I have $a_n = \lambda + \mu (\beta - 1)^n$ , as $n$ increases, $(\beta - 1)^n$ converges to $0$ and therefore the limit is $\lambda$ ?

Comment: since $a_0,a_1$ are giving in your question, i want give $\lambda$ as function of these  data($a_0,a_1$), we found: $\lambda=\frac{a_0(\beta -1)-a_1}{\beta - 2}$, tien:  $\lim\limits_{n \to + \infty}(a_n)=\lambda=\frac{a_0(\beta -1)-a_1}{\beta - 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, any constant $B$ is a solution. A second independent solution is found by letting

$$a(n)=A q^n$$

Inserting this into the recursion gives

$$q=\beta -1$$

Hence the general solution is

$$a(n)=A (\beta -1)^n+B$$

As $0<\beta < 1$ the term with $A$ goes to zero for large $n$, and the limit is $B$, i.e. finite.

Comment: Dear unknown user: please give a reason for downvoting my solution.